# Removing an NSNumber from a dictionary keeps returning 0 for long value

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber

**Problem:** I'm trying to retrieve an NSNumber from a dictionary but the long value stored in the dictionary is cleared to 0 upon retrieval.

The code below passes the *NSNumber* variable `time_of_update` into the dictionary. `time_of_update` has a long value that comes from a timestamp and is never zero. The problem arises when trying to read `time_of_update` back from the dictionary as an NSNumber than converting it to a long. The result is always zero instead of the timestamp value it was initially set to.

```
NSMutableDictionary *_update = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:time_of_update,@"time",nil];
NSLog(@"Output: %ld",[[_update objectForKey:@"time"] longValue]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet something else earlier in your dictionary is nil. When that happens, everything that follows ends up being ignored.  So in your next line, [_update objectForKey:@"time"] is probably nil, which turns the long into 0.

When you NSLog() [_update objectForKey:@"time"] is it nil?

Comment: Good call. It was returning nil. I'm new to objective c, null/nil pointers don't throw exceptions?

Comment: It depends, but most often in objc, no they don't.  In your case, nil is used as a sentinel to inform the method you are done passing parameters. So you get this subtle bug sometimes where you pass nil too early and unexpectedly.

Comment: This is tricky because the value for time_of_update is not till but the whole object returned from the dictionary is actually nil.

Comment: I mean the value I'm passing into the dictionary is not nil.